# Have all drop down lists update with choice made in first drop down - Excel

Tags: excel

I have created a drop down list using data validation and placed this on a worksheet named 'data'.
I have named the range and then in the other worksheets I have placed this drop down list.

What I would like is that whatever item from the list was selected from the drop down menu on the first worksheet would automatically be reflected in all the other worksheets where the same drop down list is placed. However, should the user choose a different option on any subsequent worksheet then this choice would not impact any other selections.

e.g. if the list was a range of locations; New York, Paris, Tokyo etc. and I have ten worksheets all with drop down lists then if I select New York on worksheet one then all ten worksheets default to New York, but if on say worksheet 7 I select Paris then this doesn't affect any of the others. Is this possible?

Comment: Definitely possible with VBA. Is that an option?

Comment: Yes, if you could suggest how I could that then I'll give it a go.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change